# Optimising matrix calculation

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, parallelization, vector, numerical-value

I was calculating the elements of a matrix like this:

```
Q = Table[Table[, S], S];
For[i = 1, i <= S, i++,
  For[j = 1, j <= S, j++,
    Q[[i, j]] =  (* Numerical calculation that depends on both `i` and `j`*);
    ] (* End For *);
  ] (* End For *) ;
```

Then I tried this:

```
Q = Table[Table[, S], S]; (* Probably this is no longer needed *)
Q = ParallelTable[
(* Numerical calculation that depends on both `i` and `j`*)   
,
   {i, 1, S}, {j, 1, S}];
```

In this way, I was able to reduce elapsed time (`AbsoluteTiming`) in a 50%, approximately. However, the computing time still remains unacceptably long for high values of `S` (the order of the square matrix `Q`).

What else can I try?

Comment: You could try to [`Compile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Compile.html) your expression for `Q[[i,j]]`. If you need more detailed suggestions, consider adding code for your calculations, as it is difficult to help when we don't know more about what you're trying to do

Comment: The bottleneck is likely not in the looping construct, but the calculation of individual elements. That means that it's impossible to say much without knowing what you are calculating. For readability and reliability, consider `Do` instead of `For` when `Table` doesn't work. You can safely forget about `For` for this kind of use. If you use `Table`, use two iterators instead of nesting.

Comment: This is mostly unanswerable unless you provide the expression for evaluating the matrix elements. I'll release the hold as soon as you edit your question.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a few tips on tuning lists. Consider the function `f[x_]:=x^2` to be computed 10^6 times and comparing the time of each method:

```
Clear[f]
list = Table[RandomReal[{0, 10}], {i, 1, 10^6}];
sz = Length[list];
list2 = Table[0, {sz}];

f[x_] := x^2;

t1 = AbsoluteTiming[Map[f, list]];
Print["time Map = ", t1[[1]]];
t2 = AbsoluteTiming[f /@ list];
Print["time /@ = ", t2[[1]]];
t3 = AbsoluteTiming[f[#] &@list];
Print["time f[#]&@ = ", t3[[1]]];
t4 = AbsoluteTiming[Table[f[list[[i]]], {i, 1, sz}]];
Print["time Table = ", t4[[1]]];
t5 = AbsoluteTiming[Do[list2[[i]] = f[list[[i]]], {i, 1, sz}]];
Print["time Do = ", t5[[1]]];
t6 = AbsoluteTiming[
   For[i = 1, i <= sz, i++, list2[[i]] = f[list[[i]]]]];
Print["time For = ", t6[[1]]];



(*  time Map = 0.648596
    time /@ = 0.646969
    time f[#]&@ = 0.00440807
    time Table = 1.23878
    time Do = 1.96579
    time For = 2.54599*)
```

**EDIT**

Things get's faster when `Compile` is used:

```
Clear[f]
list = Table[RandomReal[{0, 10}], {i, 1, 10^6}];
sz = Length[list];
list2 = Table[0, {sz}];

f = Compile[{{x, _Real}}, x^2];
t1 = AbsoluteTiming[Map[f, list]];
Print["time Map = ", t1[[1]]];
t2 = AbsoluteTiming[f /@ list];
Print["time /@ = ", t2[[1]]];
t3 = AbsoluteTiming[f &@list];
Print["time f&@ = ", t3[[1]]];
t7 = AbsoluteTiming[Function[#^2] /@ list];
Print["Function[#^2]/@list= ", t7[[1]]];
t4 = AbsoluteTiming[Table[f[list[[i]]], {i, 1, sz}]];
Print["time Table = ", t4[[1]]];
t5 = AbsoluteTiming[Do[list2[[i]] = f[list[[i]]], {i, 1, sz}]];
Print["time Do = ", t5[[1]]];
t6 = AbsoluteTiming[
   For[i = 1, i <= sz, i++, list2[[i]] = f[list[[i]]]]];
Print["time For = ", t6[[1]]];

(*time Map = 0.0258033
time /@ = 0.0270923
time f&@ = 2.11302*10^-6
Function[#^2]/@list= 0.0275185
time Table = 0.163228
time Do = 1.55715
time For = 2.12429*)
```

Comment: Could you explain why `f[#] &@list` is faster than `Map[f, list]`? I thought there were the same, as `f @ list` (I don't have MMA at hand right now to check).

Comment: @understood  I don't know for sure why it is faster, but it could be because  `f[#] &@list` can directly accept a list without using Map, and this is more efficient.

Comment: @anderstood Yes, `f[#]& @ list` is a more cumbersome, but very common, way of doing `f @ list`. As for speed, if `list` is a packed array, then vectorizable operations (e.g., Sin, Power, etc) that rely on packed array listability will be much faster than using Map, even if Map is compiled. See [What is a Mathematica packed array?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3496/45431).